# How to center these boxes in CSS when resizing page?

Tags: html, css

**I have the following boxes (articles)**

[image]

**When I try to resize the page, it becomes like this:**

[image]

I would like it to automatically center while resizing the window to avoid that huge gap on the right side, BUT it needs to be in the same format as it already is. Basically just move the entire group to the center without centering individual boxes, as I would like them to float to the left as they are shown in the picture.

**EDIT:** This is what I'm after:

[image]

Here is my current css:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.container {
    width: 90%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: skyblue;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
}

.container article {
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background: blue;
    margin: 25px
}
```

and my html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Shop</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <article>
                <h2>Hello</h2>
            </article>
            <article>
                <h2>Hello</h2>
            </article>
            <article>
                <h2>Hello</h2>
            </article>
            <article>
                <h2>Hello</h2>
            </article>
            <article>
                <h2>Hello</h2>
            </article>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Consider to use flexbox instead floating elements. There are a lot of tutorials online about centering elements with flexbox

Comment: You can also try CSS grid to preserve the layout

Comment: Could you include a picture of how you'd like it to show. I don't think I understand your explanation.

Comment: @RichardGarside Added

Comment: The @ne1410s answer is correct, with flexbox (or grid) you can achieve your goal. Just work on a little bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**@ne1410s**'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60559702/10787532) works, but it doesn't wrap the boxes around from the left, so instead I solved it using CSS grids:

**HTML:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Title</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="grid-container">
            <div class="grid-item">1</div>
            <div class="grid-item">2</div>
            <div class="grid-item">3</div>  
            <div class="grid-item">4</div>
            <div class="grid-item">5</div>
            <div class="grid-item">6</div>  
            <div class="grid-item">7</div>
            <div class="grid-item">8</div>
            <div class="grid-item">9</div>
            <div class="grid-item">10</div>
            <div class="grid-item">11</div> 
            <div class="grid-item">12</div> 
            <div class="grid-item">13</div> 
            <div class="grid-item">14</div> 
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```css
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 200px);
    grid-gap: 40px;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 40px 10px 40px 40px;
    background-color: #2196F3;
}
.grid-item {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

**NOTES:**

- `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 200px);` **200px** is the width of the box.
- `justify-content: center`; is for centering the container along with the boxes. This works, but leaves the boxes slighly off center towards the right side. To compensate, I added **10px** padding to the right side: `padding: 40px 10px 40px 40px`. The values may differ.

Working **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Cuadrix/m8Lx6fea/8/)**

Answer (score 2):

Use the flex, Luke

```
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: center;
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.container {
    width: 90%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: skyblue;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

.container article {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background: blue;
    margin: 25px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Shop</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <article>
                <h2>Hello</h2>
            </article>
            <article>
                <h2>Hello</h2>
            </article>
            <article>
                <h2>Hello</h2>
            </article>
            <article>
                <h2>Hello</h2>
            </article>
            <article>
                <h2>Hello</h2>
            </article>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Already did that, but that also centers individual boxes when they are wrapped after resizing. I'd like them to be in the format shown in the second picture, floating from the left.

Comment: I dont believe you can directly use css to determine when wrapping has occurred. However, you could put in a `@media` query (e.g. max-width less than or equal to 768px or whatever), which then switched `justify-content` to `flex-start`.